# Android NdefFormattable tag write error

Tags: android, nfc

```
07-10 15:27:48.158: W/System.err(1300): java.io.IOException
07-10 15:27:48.158: W/System.err(1300):     at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.connect(BasicTagTechnology.java:85)
07-10 15:27:48.158: W/System.err(1300):     at android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.connect(NdefFormatable.java:47)
```

The above error is what i get when i try writing an NdefFormattable fresh empty tag using

```
NdefFormatable nf = NdefFormatable.get(localTag);
nf.connect();
nf.format(nm);
```

where nm is a correctly formatted `NdefMessage`.

I have no idea why this error is coming. This is android api-15.

Also, i know IO has got to do with the actual writing process. But the tag i'm trying to write is in the same place as when it is read!

Comment: Did you first connect to the tag using another technology, for example `IsoDep` or `MifareClassic`? (You should close that connection first before connecting on `NdefFormatable`.)

Comment: No i have not opened any other connection. This is the first connection that is being opened.

Comment: Though i have one question,
`intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)` is the function i'm using to get the NDEF_MESSAGES if there any. I'm going under the assumption that does not open an IO connection separately as it does when using IsoDep.connect() function.

Comment: No, this does not create any connection, it just retrieves the bytes from the intent.

Comment: Well then i have no idea why this error occurs!

Comment: Yes, the cause is not immediately clear. What kind of tag is it? What IC is inside? (You can check with an app like [TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite).)

Comment: DESFire EV1 is the tag. It has a ferrite layer in it.

Comment: To rule out that your code is the problem, you could try using [TagWriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter) to write an NDEF message to the tag. If that also fails, then the tag (or the phone) is the problem.